# Google Contacts Download is Timing Out

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, google-contacts-api, google-api-dotnet-client

On my MVC (C#) website users can login using their OAuth credentials and download email ids from their google contacts.
I am using the following code:-

```
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
        ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
        query.NumberToRetrieve = 10;
        query.StartIndex = 1;
```

as it is explained on -

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

But, is timing out. I have nearly 3000 contacts and the query is trying to download all 3000 contacts (I can see it when I debug the for loop). 
How do I make the download faster?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: I debugged the code part which downloads email ids from Google Account. It processes all 3000 contacts from google contacts at one time in a for loop. Is there a way by which I can download 10 contacts each time? I can make the page like an Infinite Scroll Page so that when user scrolls down the request will call each 10 contacts.